# Send attachments via wp_mail from temporary folder

Tags: uploads, wp-mail, input

Is it possible to send attachment via `wp_mail`, using temporary file, instad of uploading them to any actual folder on server?

For example:

```
<input type="file" name="file">

$attachment[] = $_FILES['file']['name'];

wp_mail(....,$attachment);
```

Documentation:

> The filenames in the $attachments attribute have to be filesystem
>   paths.

How can i get the path for temporary file (if this is possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. it's possible. Attachment file contents are taken by wp_mail call.

Use `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` for filename

Comment: The file extension and content is not correct. Does not work.